# How to use custom navigations between Visualforce page embedded with LWC and local UI components without LWC in Hybrid_lwc app

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, ios, salesforcesdk

I have created on project using forcehybrid command for Salesforce hybrid mobile App.
It is using Lightening Web Components (LWC) for UI. I want to also use local UIs created via HTML/JS with LWC. How I can manage navigation between LWC and local HTML/JS UI components.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Navigation from one lWC to another is not supported in salesforce to navigate to one lwc from another, create an aura component with interface  lightning:isUrlAddressable and embed the lwc component inside the aura component. Now you are ready to navigate to aura component from LWC.

where is the document for navigation from lwc to aura component.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_basic

Documentation for Page reference type-

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_page_reference_type